# Omniauth-twitter returns 401

Tags: oauth, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

**Stage**:

I have a Rails app, it should authenticate users using their twitter account, so I use Omniauth-Twitter gem.

I have configured one app in `dev.twitter.com` enabling `Sign in with twitter` flag and getting `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`.

I was following this guide https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#readme

In Rails app, I have configured some files:

- `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

  ```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    # Twitter consumer data
    CONSUMER_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    CONSUMER_SECRET='yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
    provider :twitter, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET
  end
  ```
- `sessions_controller.rb` looks like:

  ```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
    end
  end
  ```
- `applications.html.erb` layout:

  ```
  <div id="user_nav">
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", "/auth/twitter" %>
  </div>
  ```

  So I except that when I clic on `Sign in with Twitter` link, I raises an exception showing me authentication data or requesting me Twitter autorization.

**Problem**:

Instead of this, it returns back this:

```
OAuth::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized):
oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:29:in `request_phase'
omniauth-twitter (0.0.15) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:63:in `request_phase'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:207:in `request_call'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:174:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: did you setup your callback URl right?. You gotta fix it if working from production and development envs.

Comment: @shayonj, Which URL should be right if I want to develop in localhost?

Comment: which ever shows up in your browser , along with :3000 :)

Comment: @shayonj, I have tried to put:
`http://localhost:3000/`, `http://localhost:3000`, `localhost:3000/`
, `localhost:3000`. But Twitter says that it is not a valid URL format.

Comment: @shayonj Hey! I have tried with `http://120.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback/` and it works. Thank you

Comment: try `http://127.0.0.1:3000` or `http://127.0.0.0:3000` . which ever points right to your localhost